# How to use summary field conditionally for display?

Tags: views, nodes

I have created a content type **Band** with a Description field (as Long Text and Summary). When I am viewing the Band page, I want to see the full description field. And when I am viewing a listing of bands, I want to see a summary description or the first hundred characters if the summary description is missing.

How do I show appropriate Description for the Band page and the listing pages?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan  ,I have updated my que.. **Description** field is  type of  "Long Text and summary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Description* text field needs to be of type `Long text and summary`.

With view modes (**admin/structure/types/manage/band/display**) you can configure how the fields must be rendered.

In the view mode `Teaser` you could set the format to `Summary or trimmed` and in other view modes to `Default`.

When viewing the content type *Band* as a full page you can render the view mode `Default`. When rendering a list of *Bands* with views you can set the view mode to `Teaser`.